# iCloud: How to store data not in documents?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, icloud

I have an iOS application that stores a lot of user-generated data in the iCloud documents folder. How can I disable this syncing?

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: What "syncing" are you talking about? The iCloud backup?

Comment: The user has to disable iCloud backup on a per-application basis. Settings -> iCloud -> Storage and Backup -> Manage Storage -> [Device Name] -> Backup Options

Comment: Alright, and how can I change the iCloud backup folder?

Answer (score 0):

Please read this documentation on iCloud Data Storage (login required):

https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/